# List<WebElement> is not storing all the required elements in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, debugging, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My myntra wishlist has 41 products, of which 19 are out of stock. I tried printing the names of the 'out of stock' products.

'out of stock' elements had a common class name using which I identified the product's name using xpath by traversing through parent and child nodes.

when i validated it in console, it gave the right response. It showed **19** products and when i hovered the mouse pointer it highlighted the out of stock products as expected. Works as expected when i debugged the code too.

But when i hit run, it printed only 7 products, size of the list was **7**.

The page initially displays top **20** products and later displays the remaining as we scroll down. Out of the top 20, **7** are out of stock. Could this be a reason. If that is the case, how to handle this scroll event?

Here's the code snippet:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
 
public class stockout {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path of chromedriver.exe");  
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        WebDriverWait w =new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        
        driver.get(myntra login page);
    //enter phone number          driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//div[@class='signInContainer']/div[2]/div/input"))).sendKeys(phone number);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.submitBottomOption")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='bottomeLink']/span")).click();
    //enter password
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn.primary.lg.block.submitButton")).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    //open wishlist
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.myntraweb-sprite.desktop-iconWishlist.sprites-headerWishlist")).click();
    //add out of stock elements to a list
        List<WebElement> outofstock = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[@class='itemcard-outOfStockItemImage itemcard-itemImage']/parent::picture/parent::a/parent::div/parent::div/div[2]/div/p[1]"));
    //explicit wait
            w.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(outofstock));
        System.out.println(outofstock.size());
        System.out.println("Items out of stock:");
        for (WebElement product: outofstock)
        {   System.out.println(product.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution on the net, but wondering if there's any simpler way to do this. Suggestions are welcomed.

I added this piece of code to scroll down and it worked:

```
try {
        Object lastHeight = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.body.scrollHeight");

        while (true) {
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            Object newHeight = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.body.scrollHeight");
            if (newHeight.equals(lastHeight)) {
                break;
            }
            lastHeight = newHeight;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code if you are expecting a specific number of elements to be present.

new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBe(By by, 19));

Comment: Thanks @Ledjon, but the issue was not about the wait. It was about the dynamic page load based on vertical scroll.